# Direct url-access to my projects on vmWare/Debian 6 / Apache2 from Windows 7

Tags: php, apache2, virtualhost

I am a web-programmer and I was looking for a solution to host my local projects on Linux, working from Windows 7.

So I installed VMWare Workstation, and created a virtual machine with OS Debian 6 Squeeze. After that I configured the internet connection with NAT, setup apache2, mysql and php.

Now I can access my sites from Windows by IP "http://192.168.195.222/somepoject" or by hostname (I edited hosts file in Windows) "http://myvirt/somepoject" and all seems great. But the problem is that I want to access every project (for which I created a virtual host in Debian) directly by its hostname (hostname of virtual host), for example "http://someproject.local" instead of "http://192.168.195.222/someproject".

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you want to have an absolute URL for each project on localhost.
If true, you can set any project on specific port.
For this, input this code in your httpd.conf :

For project one:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
DocumentRoot /home/poject1
</VirtualHost>
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
```

For project two:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:9090>
DocumentRoot /home/poject2
</VirtualHost>
Listen 127.0.0.1:9090
```

Finally, you can access to project one with /home/poject1 root path, with this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

And you can access to project two with /home/poject2 root path, with this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9090/
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget the hosts file, he is on Windows 7.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution!
I configured httpd.conf like you said. Now i can access my project in debian by url http://127.0.0.1:8080 but I still cannot access it from Windows by url http://192.168.195.222:8080/ 
What should I do?